# Making new files from source text file

Tags: shell, unix

I have a text file and in that text file there are some lines that start with #. What I am trying to do is make new files from the lines that start with #. So for example in the text file if there is a line that starts with the text " # FutureExams " then the script would take that line and make a new file called FutureExams.txt The script I came up with currently runs but doesn't give me any result.

```
find . -name "Data.txt" | while read line; do 
    if [ "$line" == "#"* ]; then 
        touch "$line".txt
    fi
done
```

Perhaps there is a more simpler way of writing the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a pipe of GNU sed and xargs like this

```
sed -rn "/^#/ {s/^#(.*)/\1.txt/g;p}" Data.txt | xargs touch
```

- the sed filters for lines starting with # and apply the `s` and `p` commands to such lines
- the `s` command captures everything following the # into `\1` for reuse in the replacement part, where it appends `.txt` to it
- the p command prints the modified string to the pipe
- the xargs forwards each string to the touch command

Comment: When I tried it running I received the error message extra characters at the end of p command

Comment: @NIckJ I am using gnu sed 4.2.2

Answer (score 0):

You can try below program -

```
vipin@kali:~$ cat kk.txt
vipin
#file1.txt
kumar
#file2.txt
vipin@kali:~$ cat kk.sh
while read line
do
var1=`cut -c1 <<<$line`          ### cut first character
if [ "$var1" == "#" ]; then
   var2=`cut -c2- <<<$line`      ### cut from 2nd till last character of line
   touch $var2                   ### create file
fi
done < kk.txt
vipin@kali:~$ date
Sat Oct 29 22:10:27 EDT 2016
vipin@kali:~$ ./kk.sh
vipin@kali:~$ ls -ltr |tail -2
-rw-r--r-- 1 vipin vipin     0 Oct 29 22:10 file1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 vipin vipin     0 Oct 29 22:10 file2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple one-liner using `grep`, `cut` and `touch`:

`for i in $(grep '^#' Data.txt |cut -c2-); do touch "$i".txt; done`